# Данные какой ветки будут в новой ветке git?

Tags: git

Пользователь переходит в новую локальную ветку. Данные какой ветки будут в ней находиться?

Comment: Что значит «переходит в новую локальную ветку»?

Comment: Смотря от какой ветки создали ветку)

Comment: Вопрос надо задавать внятно, добавляя в него всю требуемую информацию, а не надеяться на телепатов

Answer (score 1):

Если "новая ветка" это бранч, созданный перед этим при помощи `git branch`, то очевидно после прочтения [документации по команде](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), что результат будет зависеть от полного формата использованной команды, так как там "все не так однозначно" (с)

- При использовании **только** [`<branchname>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt-ltbranchnamegt) выполняется условие

> `<start-point>` ... If this option is omitted, the current HEAD will
> be used instead.

- При использовании и `<branchname>` и [`<start-point>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt-ltstart-pointgt) бранч будет создан из коммита `<start-point>`, и значит - из бранча этого коммита
- При создании "новой локальной ветки" (фу, какая *шишковщина*) методом опции [`--copy`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---copy) (нуачо?! новая жи!) копия будет сдержать данные оригинала

Если все вышенаписанное непонятно, то см. мой коммент, ибо мои возможности всё